# Chrome extension - Localstorage not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, local-storage

I'm writing a Chrome extension that uses a content script to modify certain parts of a website.  The content script worked fine until I tried to add an options page to my extension.

Right now I'm using an options.html file to save user preferences to localstorage, as you can see here:

```
    <html>
    <head><title>Options</title></head>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        function save_options() {
            var select = document.getElementById("width");
            var width = select.children[select.selectedIndex].value;
            localStorage["site_width"] = width;
        }

        function restore_options() {
          var fwidth = localStorage["site_width"];
          if (!fwidth) {
            return;
          }
          var select = document.getElementById("width");
          for (var i = 0; i < select.children.length; i++) {
            var child = select.children[i];
            if (child.value == fwidth) {
              child.selected = "true";
              break;
            }
          }
        }

        </script>

    <body onload="restore_options()">

    Width:
        <select id="width">
            <option value="100%">100%</option>
            <option value="90%">90%</option>
            <option value="80%">80%</option>
            <option value="70%">70%</option>
        </select>

        <br>
        <button onclick="save_options()">Save</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

I also have a background.html file to handle the communication between the content script and the localstorage:

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
            if (request.method == "siteWidth")
                sendResponse({status: localStorage["site_width"]});
            else
                sendResponse({});
        });

    </script>
</html>
```

Then there's the actual content script that looks like this:

```
var Width;

chrome.extension.sendRequest({method: "siteWidth"}, function(response) {
        width = response.status;
    });
```

None of that code actually works.  It looks solid enough to me but I'm not a very experienced programmer so I might be wrong.

Could someone explain localstorage to me in layman's terms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To learn how localStorage works and in detail [Complete details about LocalStorage](http://web.archive.org/web/20100106033106/http://www.rajdeepd.com/articles/chrome/localstrg/LocalStorageSample.htm) is a good source for you to begin with. Just to add I will give you an example which might help you. This is the **options.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javscript'>
function save_options() {
    if(document.getElementById("x").checked == true){localStorage['x_en'] = 1;}
    if(document.getElementById("x").checked == false){localStorage['x_en'] = 0;}
}

function restore_options() {
  var x_opt = localStorage['x_en'];
  if (x_opt == 0) {document.getElementById('x').checked = false;}else{
     var select = document.getElementById('x');select.checked = true; localStorage['x_en'] = 1;}
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="restore_options()">
<table border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" align="center">
    <tr class='odd'><td><input type='checkbox' id='x' onclick="save_options()"/></td><td>X</td></tr>
</table>
```

To access this you need to have a background.html page which can be as shown below.

```
alert(localStorage['x_en']); //Will alert the localStorage value.
```

If you want to access the localStorage from the Content Script you can't directly access it by the above method. You need to use the concept called Message Passing (http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) which can pass the values from the background to content scripts. Just as Sergey said this might be an issue with the typo.

Comment: reference http://www.rajdeepd.com/articles/chrome/localstrg/LocalStorageSample.htm is dead

Comment: @olegtaranenko Here's a mirror http://web.archive.org/web/20100106033106/http://www.rajdeepd.com/articles/chrome/localstrg/LocalStorageSample.htm

Answer (score 3):

The `window.localStorage` has getters and setters that need to be used in order to access the internal object map.

So, to set:

```
localStorage.setItem(key, value);
```

To get:

```
localStorage.getItem(key);
```

To clear map:

```
localStorage.clear();
```

To remove item:

```
localStorage.removeItem(key);
```

To get length:

```
localStorage.length
```

To key based on index in internal map:

```
localStorage.key(index);
```

To read more: http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#the-storage-interface

The `window.localStorage` implements the `Storage` interface:

```
interface Storage {
 readonly attribute unsigned long length;
 DOMString key(in unsigned long index);
 getter any getItem(in DOMString key);
 setter creator void setItem(in DOMString key, in any value);
 deleter void removeItem(in DOMString key);
 void clear();
};
```

Comment: Sure but its also valid to use localStorage["key"] syntax. Why is it not working in the question code?

Answer (score 0):

Using accessors isn’t mandatory, feel free to use [] operator to get and set values, and “in” operator to test if key exists.

However, it looks like there’s a typo in your content script:

> var **Width**;
>
> chrome.extension.sendRequest({method:
>   "siteWidth"}, function(response) {
>           **width** = response.status;
>       });

Since JavaScript is case-sensitive, these two are different variables.

Answer (score -1):

try using `window.localStorage.getItem/setItem` instead of `localStorage["site_width"]`