# Doesn't Google extension share localstorage?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I develop google extension.

I defined `popup.html` in the `manifest.js`

```
  "browser_action" : {
    "default_icon": "icon19.png",
    "default_popup" : "popup.html"
  },
```

And, import `myscript.js` in `popup.html`

```
<script src="myscript.js"></script>
```

It store value in localStrage.

```
localStorage['myid1_save'] = 'some value'.
```

I also define content_scripts in the manifest.js
it calls background.js.

in the `background.js`.

```
var myid1_save = localStorage['myid1_save'];
alert(myid1_save); // -> undefined
```

it can't call localStorage value which popup.html saved

How to fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome extension - Localstorage not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323550/chrome-extension-localstorage-not-working)

Comment: Also have a look at this: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

Comment: I watched your link
And I tried `localStorage.setItem(key, value);`
and
`localStorage.getItem(key);`
but can't work.

Comment: Could it be you're trying to read it before it is saved? In principle, `localStorage` is shared between background and popup, but not with content scrips.

Comment: `content_scripts` use the pages localStorage, not your extensions.

Comment: No. Hes not saving from content script, hes saving from popup and reading from background which should be ok.